# How to create list of items from another list

Tags: c#, linq

How can I create a list from items in another list?

```
    List<Post> postList = db.Posts.Where(u => u.PostId == postId).ToList();
    List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(u => u.PostId **** is equal to PostId within postList**** );
```

I used the ****'s to show where my understanding falls apart.

Comment: See msdn for examples using linq.  I think in some cases you will need to use the join method to combine list.  In some cases yafter the WHERE you will need to use SELECT method to get only some properties of a class instead of the entire class.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `select` the Id's from the other list, then see if that list `contains` your current Id. Although, I would generate the list of Id's first. Assuming your Id's are of type int:

```
List<Post> postList = db.Posts.Where(u => u.PostId == postId).ToList();
List<int> postIds = postList.Select(u => u.PostId).ToList();
List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(u => postIds.Contains(u.PostId)).ToList();
```

Comment: It would be better if `postIds` were a `HashSet`

Comment: All the answers seem close, but yours and abion come back with the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<App.Models.PostView>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<App.Models.PostView>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  Any ideas?

Comment: @DudeThatCodes You were declaring a List<PostView> but returning an IQueryable. My fault I didn't catch that. Just updated my answer.

Comment: I feel like everyone that responded was pretty close, but yours worked the best for me.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(
    u => postList.Any(p => p.PostId == u.PostId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(u => postList.Any(pl=>pl.postId == u.postId));
```

But you should be able to do this in one shot:

```
List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(u => u.Post.postId == postId);
```

or even

```
List<PostView> viewList = db.PostViews.Where(u => u.PostId == postId);
```

It seems a `postview` has a `post`. You shouldn't have to get a list of `posts` first and then get a list of `views` from that list.